# Why this table (ng-repeat) in angular is not sorting as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this table being populated by angular:

I let the code here, so you could see the problem live:
http://plnkr.co/edit/qzY4r2XWq1UUJVrcqBsw?p=preview

when I click the `a` elements the sort order change, however, alphabetic elements not seems to be ordered alphabetic in the table.

The same happen with the reverseOrder, Only the last column is ordering reverse

For example, try to sort by the first columns, and you will see, it is not ordered

Any idea of what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my bad, I didn't know sort variable, should have the same name as the column in ng-repeat